# Liferay AUI Autocomplete limit selection

Tags: autocomplete, liferay

During a form compilation i need to be able to insert a value, presenting a list of already used values (usual listbox behavior).
But i also need to be able to enter a new value, so i choosed aui:autocomplete (code below).

By default it allows selection of multiple items separated by the "delimChar" separator.
Is there any way to limit to 1 single value selection (or new value)?

```
var catArray = new Array();
    <%for (String s : categoryList) {%>
        catArray.push('<%=s%>');
    <%} %>
    var autoCompleteCategory = new A.AutoComplete( 
    { 
        contentBox: '#<portlet:namespace />contactOptions',
        input:'#<portlet:namespace/>category',
        dataSource: catArray, 
        delimChar: ',', 
        typeAhead: true, 
    }).render();
```

Comment: What if you don't include the attribute `delimchar: ','`? I think if you don't include it should work as if it can take only one element. Try it. Also clear your browser cache before trying it :-)

Comment: nice suggestion! it works, thaks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513235/liferay-aui-autocomplete-limit-selection#comment16930531_12513235) as the answer for better visibility:

You can remove the attribute `delimchar: ','` from the following code:

```js
var catArray = new Array();
    <%for (String s : categoryList) {%>
        catArray.push('<%=s%>');
    <%} %>
    var autoCompleteCategory = new A.AutoComplete( 
    { 
        contentBox: '#<portlet:namespace />contactOptions',
        input:'#<portlet:namespace/>category',
        dataSource: catArray, 
        delimChar: ',', // **remove this attribute**
        typeAhead: true, 
    }).render();
```

I think this should work.

Also clear your browser cache before trying it :)